# Question about how to use martingale decomposition to bound the variance of a random variable.

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales

- Question:

Let $Z=f(X_1,...,X_n)$ be a function of $n$ independent random variables $X_1,...,X_n$. Let $X_i'$ be an
independent copy of $X_i$. Use martingale decomposition to prove
$$
\text{var}[Z]\le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n E[(f(X_1,...,X_{i-1},X_i',X_{i+1},...,X_n)-f(X_1,...,X_n))^2]
$$

- Other information:

1. Our professor gives a hint: first prove for an arbitrary random variable $Y$, if $Y'$is an independent copy, then $\text{var}[Y]=\frac{1}{2}E[(Y-Y')^2]$. This is easy to do, just a direct calculation.
2. By martingale decomposition, I think our prof refers to the following operation:
   let X be an arbitrary random variable $X\in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. $\mathcal{F}_0=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}\subset \mathcal{F}_1\subset ... \subset \mathcal{F}_n=\mathcal{F}$ is a filtration. Then let $X_i=E[X|\mathcal{F}_i]$, we have the following decompostion:
   $$
   X = E[X] + \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - X_{i-1}
   $$
   From this, by the orthogonality of martingale increments, we will get:
   $$
   \text{var}[X]=\sum_{i=1}^n E[(X_i-X_{i-1})^2]= \sum_{i=1}^n E[\text{var}[X_i|\mathcal{F_i}]]
   $$
   Our Prof says $\text{var}[X_i|\mathcal{F_i}]$ can be controlled by coupling techs, but I do not know how to deal with it, and I cannot find some materials about this method.

Could someone help me with it? Thanks a lot.